# What is 'def' in Groovy stands for

Tags: function, variables, groovy, closures

We are using def for declaring variables and defining functions with

```
def myVariable

def getMyVar = {}

def getMyVariable () {}
```

What are these def defines? And how it identifies either function/ closure or method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `def` keyword in Groovy, the actual type holder is Object so you can assign any object to variables defined with def, and return any kind of object if a method is declared returning def. `def` keyword is used for untyped variables whose type is defined dynamically at runtime.

Here are 3 definitions using `def` and the equivalent with Object as the type. The first defines an untyped variable and the second defines a variable assigned with an empty closure. The third defines the return type of a method.

```
def myVariable                  // Object myVariable

def getMyVar = {}               // Object getMyVar = {}

def getMyVariable() {}          // Object getMyVariable() {}
```

Note if assigning primitive number values (e.g int, float, etc.) to a `def` variable, it will auto-convert primitive types to an object instance of class Integer, Float, etc.

The [Groovy Style Guide](https://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html) ([#3](https://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_def_and_type) and [#21](https://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_optional_typing_advice)) gives some guidelines on when to use optional typing with `def` and when to use explicit strong typing.

Comment: Then what is def stands for - define / definition ... anything like that ?

Comment: `def` is a groovy keyword used to define a variable, field or method as dynamically typed. It can be thought of as `Object` but it is not the same